# Wix ToolSet: Conditionally Setting a <Environment />

Tags: wix, environment

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so please be patient with me.

I am looking for a way to conditionally set a `<Environment />` element given a `<Property />`.

The solutions that were given to me are kind of ugly in my opinion. Something like this was proposed:

```
<Component Id='Component1' Gui:'GUID1'>
  ...A lot of Stuff...
  <Condition>[PROPERTY]=Value</Condition>
</Component>

<Component Id='Component2' Gui:'GUID2'>
  ...A lot of Stuff...
  <Environment Id='ENV' ... />
  <Condition>[PROPERTY]<>Value</Condition>
</Component>
```

Isn't there any other way to do this with just one  block?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put a condition on a component or on a feature.  The feature / components  then evaluate and they are installed atomically.  You can't put a condition on a single file, registry value, environment variable and so on.

Your example shows mutually exclusive components.  FWIW you shouldn't duplicate files between those components.  Have one component with no condition install the files and have one component with a condition install the environment change.

Comment: Thanks! Since Wix is not imperative, but descriptive, I should've know already that this was the only solution.

Comment: WiX XML/XSD is a thin abstraction of the underlying Windows Installer database.  It helps to read the MSI SDK and look at the built MSI using ORCA to see the PK / FK relationships to see what can and cant be declared.  Also please feel free to accept this answer.